# Why code is not working to avoid duplicate insert/update of Account with same name

Tags: trigger

```java
trigger Account14 on Account (before insert, before update) {
    List<String> AccList = new List<String>();
    
    if(trigger.isbefore && (trigger.isupdate || trigger.isInsert))
    {
        if(!trigger.new.isempty())
        {
            for (Account acc :trigger.new)
            {
                AccList.add(acc.Name);
            }
        }
        
        Map<String, Account> AccMap = new Map<String, Account>([SELECT Name, Phone, Description FROM Account WHERE Name IN :AccList]);
            
        for(Account accs :trigger.new)
        {
            if(AccMap.containsKey(accs.Name))
            {
                accs.Name.addError('Duplicate Name');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider using a Duplicate rule for this instead (using standard features is pretty much always preferred over writing custom code).

Answer (score 0):

You have stored query results in the `Map<String, Account>`. This will not store `Name` as a key. This will store `Id` as a key into the map that's why a duplicate error is not thrown.

Try this code:

```
trigger Account14 on Account (before insert, before update) {
    
        Map<String, Account> mapOfAccount = new Map<String, Account>();    
       
        for (Account acc : trigger.new){
                if(trigger.isbefore && (trigger.isInsert || acc.Name != trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).Name)){
                        if (mapOfAccount.containsKey(acc.Name)) {
                                acc.Name.addError('Another new Account has the same name.');
                        } else {
                                mapOfAccount.put(acc.Name, acc);
                        }
                }
        }

        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :mapOfAccount.KeySet()]) {
                Account newAccount = mapOfAccount.get(acc.Name);
                newAccount.Name.addError('A Account with this name already exists.');
        }   
                
}
```

Comment: This will surely not work when updating fields other than Name on an existing Account record? At that point it will complain that the Account is a duplicate of itself...?

Comment: Thanks, @PhilW. I have updated the code.

Comment: `accList.size()` will never be empty (Name is a required field) - this `if` can be removed. The code also doesn't check for duplicates intra-transaction